# Alt or Redux? Which flux implementation will suit a WYSIWYG react app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, flux, reactjs-flux

After doing much research I found out that Redux and Alt are two really popular flux implementations.

I also found that Alt is more of traditional flux pattern and Redux is slightly different from the traditional flux. In Redux, the state is stored as immutable tree which means there will be a new object created for every change.

Now coming to my question, I have a requirement to develop a WYSIWYG authoring  platform. This means that the contents of this app will keep changing every few seconds.

So does this mean that  using Redux for this app will be a bad option as there will be thousands of objects in the memory as we start editing the content. Is alt implementation a better option?

Which flux implementation makes more sense?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen any evidence that Redux's immutability paradigm is bad for performance. (I don't say that to be rude or dismissive, I would love to see the evidence if it exists.)

Frankly I don't think what you choose as your data layer is a major concern here. In a WYSIWYG app, the bulk of your complexity is going to be in the view layer.

My advice would be to make sure you write your app in a way that the data layer can easily be swapped out and replaced. That way, if you do find your chosen framework is a performance hog, you can easily replace it.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time you have 2 main areas where front end applications can take a significant performance hit. One is memory usage (as you pointed out) and the other is DOM rendering. As far as memory usage is concern, it would be hard to hit that performance limit, unless you have a memory leak or deal with extremely large data sets. I suspect that neither of these will be a problem for you. Instead DOM rendering and efficient updating should be the focus of your decision. Here you need to look at React more than Redux. Redux utilizes the render mechanisms of React components and this can be highly optimized when encountering performance issues. If you have faith in React performance (and in my opinion you should) then either framework would work in this case.

Here are a few friends :) having a good conversation on the topic (related to Redux): https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/634

Answer (score 2):

Since the overhead of the flux implementation is not an issue, the best choice would be the implementation that is the most logical to you. You are going to be more productive using tools that make sense to you.